# Is is possible to setup a mock inside a mock?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

Just wondering it is possible to setup a mock inside a mock ? I mean a mock than get configured to return another mock which has a specific setup.

I am using Moq.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the moq site (and using what I know of RhinoMock) I suspect you could do something like:

```
var innerMock = new Mock<IInnerClass>();
// TODO - Setup innerMock expectations
var outerMock = new Mock<IOuterClass>();
outerMock.Setup(i => i.GetInner()).Returns(innerMock.Object);
```

Comment: It should be `.Returns(innerMock.Object)` IIRC.